# Law for the character of a dream?

Tags: law, deuteronomy, leviticus

In Leviticus 15:16

> 16 ‘Now if a man has a seminal emission, he shall bathe all his body
> in water and be unclean until evening.

In Deuteronomy 23:10

> 10 “If there is among you any man who is unclean because of a nocturnal
> emission, then he must go outside the camp; he may not reenter the
> camp.

Are the Scriptures holding a man responsible for the character of the dream? I ask this because "nocturnal emission" is also known (maybe only more recently) as "wet dreams" (here the word dream). According to [Johns Hopkins All Children’s Hospital](https://www.hopkinsallchildrens.org/Patients-Families/Health-Library/HealthDocNew/What-Are-Wet-Dreams#:%7E:text=Wet%20dreams%20usually%20happen%20during,more%20testosterone%2C%20a%20male%20hormone.),

> Wet dreams usually happen during dreams that have sexual images. Sometimes guys wake up from a wet dream, but sometimes they sleep through it.

I doubt this passage to be about sexual intercourse.

Comment: Where do you see the mention of a 'dream' ? I cannot find it, myself. The emission of male seed and the issuing forth of female seed (a baby) both require a sacrifice. Because they are both the issuing forth of a deadly life-form . . . . 'sin ... bringeth forth death'. _'In Adam - all die.'_ And they bring forth (issuing) more death.

Comment: "nocturnal emission" @NigelJ

Comment: . . . .  still looking for the word 'dream'. The issue under discussion is the _issue_ itself.

Comment: @NigelJ depends how one interprets "nocturnal emission", also known (maybe only more recently) as "wet dreams" (here the word dream). According to [Johns Hopkins All Children’s Hospital](https://www.hopkinsallchildrens.org/Patients-Families/Health-Library/HealthDocNew/What-Are-Wet-Dreams#:~:text=Wet%20dreams%20usually%20happen%20during,more%20testosterone%2C%20a%20male%20hormone.), "Wet dreams usually happen during dreams that have sexual images. Sometimes guys wake up from a wet dream, but sometimes they sleep through it.". Would you argue the passage to be about sexual intercourse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that nocturnal emission involves a dream.

What is the character of such a dream?

It could be either positive or negative.

Are the Scriptures holding a man responsible for the character of the dream?

No, because the character of the dream is not specified in the Scriptures.

The same reasoning applies to

> Leviticus 15:16 “ ‘When a man has an **emission of semen**, he must bathe his whole body with water, and he will be unclean till evening. 17Any clothing or leather that has semen on it must be washed with water, and it will be unclean till evening. 18When a man has sexual relations with a woman and there is an **emission of semen**, both of them must bathe with water, and they will be unclean till evening.

Regardless of the "character" of the emissions, the rule applies. There is no judgment involved.